# Repair PricePfister WL2-23 Classic Lavatory Faucet?

Tags: repair, faucet

I have a faucet that closely resembles the one found at http://bit.ly/bTTr8z the WL2-23 near the bottom right of the list.  I am having trouble removing the faucet handles in order to look at the internals/change the washer.

Has anyone ever dealt with a faucet like this?  It has no obvious access area except for the hole near the bend of the curve of the handle.  It doesn't seem to have a screw or anything in there, but I might be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, a lot of bathroom fixtures use Allen wrenches.  Mine (from Pegasus, though) use a 1/16" wrench.

Comment: that is exactly it, I should have tried that but in my madness the bottom of the well looked like it had a circular hole.  Looking again it was clearly hex shaped.  Thanks!